# AS3, FLEX - softKeyboardBehavior does not work on android device

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, mxml

I've a text area:

```
<s:TextArea id="mess" width="80%" height="90%" needsSoftKeyboard="true" styleName="label" skinClass="spark.skins.mobile.TextAreaSkin" />
```

and I want the keyboard pan when the user tap on the text field, so I using:

```
<softKeyboardBehavior>pan</softKeyboardBehavior>
```

This works perfectly on iOs, but on Android, the keyboard covers the text field...

Comment: Do you have a screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally solved... it was the render type: I've changed it from

> gpu

to

> auto

and now all works!